# Python requests analogue for -X UNLINK curl request

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I have an example of curl request:

```
curl -X UNLINK 
-H "Authorization: OAuth <>" -H 'Link: <https://some/my/url>; rel="relates"' "https://some/my/url"
```

I have already converted curl request with parameter `-X LINK` to `SESSION.patch(...)`:

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'OAuth %s' % some_token
}
params = (
    ('notify', 'False'),
)

data = '{"links":[{"relationship":"relates", "key":"some_key", "origin":"some_url"}]}'
r = SESSION.patch('https://some/url, params=params, data=data)
```

But I how to implement `-X UNLINK` using `requests`? 
As far as I know there is no method in `requests.Session()` like `unlink()`and `.delete()` is not allowed by API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in custom verbs with the [`request()` method](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.request):

```
SESSION.request('UNLINK', url, ...)
```

See the [*Custom verbs* section](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#custom-verbs) of the *Advanced* section of the `requests` documentation.

The default methods like `.get()`, `.post()` and `.patch()`, are all just wrappers for `.request()`, explicitly setting the verb.